# Embedding Python Game Into HTML Using Skulpt

Tags: python, html, embed, skulpt

I have written a game in Python using the PyGame library that I am trying to embed into an HTML page to allow me to play in a web browser.

I am attempting to do this using the JavaScript library Skulpt. I have attached a test script below that successfully outputs the print statement below.

skulpt.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="assets/skulpt/skulpt.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head>
<body> 
    <textarea id="pythonCode">
        print "I am python."
    </textarea><br /> 
    <pre id="output"></pre> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function outf(text) { 
            var mypre = document.getElementById("output"); 
            mypre.innerHTML = mypre.innerHTML + text; 
        } 

        var code = document.getElementById("pythonCode").value; 
        Sk.configure({output:outf}); 
        eval(Sk.importMainWithBody("<stdin>",false,code)); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Output of skulpt.html:

[image]

The issue that I am having is that when I use my game code instead of the simple print statement shown above it produces the error seen below;

[image]

I have included all relevant images to my web servers' directory at the correct path. I am unsure of why this error is being produced. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Also, here is the attached Python game code (and a live demo of the error):

http://nicolasward.com/portfolio/skulpt.html

Comment: Your example site is down.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of indentation on line 1 -> remember, in python, **indentation always matters**. Take away all those spaces/tabs on the first line and it should run.

Comment: After indenting I now get this for an error, `Uncaught AssertionError: Failure: unhandled expr`

Comment: Does it also give you a line number?

Comment: No line number... Only thing I can think of is pygame not being accessible through the server. Any idea on that?

Comment: I'm not sure if pygame plays nice with skulpt. I'm not even sure if pygame plays nice with anything.

Comment: Here is the code making the assertion error you're getting. I don't know much about it. You may want to research it.

goog.asserts.fail = function(opt_message, var_args) {
      if (goog.asserts.ENABLE_ASSERTS) {
        throw new goog.asserts.AssertionError(
            'Failure' + (opt_message ? ': ' + opt_message : ''),
            Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

Comment: There may be a difference in the python version that is run by Skulpt. Be sure that you have python code that **definitely** works for 2.7 **and** 3.4. Then try both and see what you get.